# Easier Way To Query Nested Shadow Element From Inside Element?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.0

I am not using shady dom, but native shadow dom in chrome.

Is there a easier way to query `<paper-checkbox name="pets" id="noPets">`? Since it is nested in `<template is="dom-if" if="{{foo}}">` I can not use `this.$.noPets`:

```
<dom-module id="foobar-element>
  <template>
...
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{foo}}">
    <paper-checkbox name="pets" id="noPets">
...
  attached: function() {
    var rootEl = Polymer.dom(document.querySelector('my-app').root);
    var level2 = Polymer.dom(rootEl).querySelector('foobar-element').root;
    Polymer.dom(level2).querySelector('#noPets').addEventListener('change', (e)=> {});
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.$$(querySelector)`

here is documentation: https://polymer.github.io/polymer/

So in you case it would be: `this.$$("#noPets")`